# Checkbox get label value - React Native

Tags: react-native

I put the label and value value in the CircleCheckBox to the selectedCheckbox state. When I get the output selectedCheckbox, it looks like this: {"label": "Commercial Vehicle", "value": 1}. How can I get the label value here?

```
class AdjustAdressScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
  checkboxValue: [
        {
          label: "1 Araç",
          value: 1
        },
        {
          label: "2 Araç",
          value: 2
        }
      ]
    };
  selectedCheckbox: {}

  CheckMe = selectedCheckbox => {
    this.setState({ selectedCheckbox }); // update selected item
  };
    render() {
            const { checkboxValue, selectedCheckbox } = this.state;
{checkboxValue.map((option, indexInArray) => {
                return (
                  <CircleCheckBox
                    key={option.value}
                    checked={option.value === selectedCheckbox.value} // for current element
                    onToggle={(value, index) => this.CheckMe(option)} // pass index of toggled element
                    labelPosition={LABEL_POSITION.RIGHT}
                    label={option.label}
                    innerColor= {'red'}
                    outerColor = {'gray'}
                    filterSize = {15}
                    styleLabel={{ fontSize: 14, fontFamily : 'Gilroy-Light' }}
                  />
                );
              })}
 );
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand it correctly but you can get the label with `selectedCheckbox.label`

Comment: When I do this.state.seciliCheckbox.label I get the output undefined @UğurEren

Comment: You will get undefined because it is not set in the initial state object. But if you set a label in it, then it will perfectly log the label value. Like this: `this.state = { selectedCheckbox: {label: 'initial label'}}`

Comment: @UğurEren It's already defined that way. I forgot to add to the topic, I updated the topic

Comment: In which line you want to get the ```this.state.selecteCheckbox.label```?  I didn't understand yet. Your function should be declared like this too ``` const CheckMe = selectedCheckbox => {
    this.setState({ selectedCheckbox }); // update selected item
  };```